# Run and show Batch file commands on telnet

Tags: windows, batch-file, ssh, telnet, prompt

Not only for the host running. Bat, but to run and display the output text to the client (Telnet)
This is possible?
I have tried and tested everything and could not.
If it is not really possible, which file should I edit to edit the text output from telnet and what language is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from what little I understood, you just want to send the output of a file to another computer using telnet. if so try file | telnet. or... cough ...
you could use netcat, if it was one time and you were carful it shouldn't pose a huge threat.

nc -lp12123 on the server, and connect with nc server 12123 -efile.bat on the client.
if neither of these suit then please post more info.